# Rails 3: MTI with Devise and Heritage?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have looked around but am unsure how to do this ->

I have 1 supertype and 2 subtypes in my db, as laid out by MTI, using the Heritage gem and with validation by Devise.

```
 class User < ActiveRecord::Base   
   acts_as_predecessor   
   devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, 
          :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable 
 end

 class SubUser1 < User   
  acts_as_heir_of :user   
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, 
          :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable  #some unique columns 
 end

 class SubUser2 < User
  acts_as_heir_of :user   
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,    :recoverable,
 :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable   #Hi,some unique columns 
end
```

But this test is failing.

```
 1) SubUser should create a new instance given a valid attribute
    Failure/Error: SubUser.create!(@attr)
    ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
    Validation failed: Predecessor password can't be blank
```

**My question is how do I test with an if statement in user model** to test which type I user I am instantiating. And in the case that i am instantiating a subuser, skip this line in user ->

```
:database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, 
      :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
```

Comment: I tried 

`if self.to_s == "User"
    devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  end`

But it did nothing..

Comment: Do you need to do all that devise-ing?
If you remove the "devise" lines from your subclasses - don't they inherit from User ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking abut testing an *instance* of a user whether or not it is a User model, then you can use:

```
if self.is_a? User
```

If you're in the class then I don't know. perhaps try something like:

```
if self.class_name == 'User'
```

but it's generally frowned upon - it's kind of a code smell to need to know what kind of User you are. It's much better to rethink the problem and figure out a better way to build your class hierarchy.

Is there a "predecessor/heir" way of doing this kind of thing? Eg "if I'm the predecessor, then..."